# How to efficiently dropna when the NaNs are contained in the index?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a series looking like this:

```
s = pd.Series(
     np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]), 
     index=np.array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   4.,  np.nan,   3.])
)

 0.0    0
 1.0    0
 2.0    1
 4.0    1
NaN     2
 3.0    2
dtype: int64
```

You'll notice the NaN in the index I want to drop. What's the *most efficient* way of dropping that row?

Expected result:

```
0.0    0
1.0    0
2.0    1
4.0    1
3.0    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Current approach:

```
s.reset_index().dropna().set_index('index').squeeze()
```

Comment: `s[s.index.notna()]`?

Comment: @MaxU Yup, how foolish to not think of that method.

Comment: @Zero Yup, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [22]: s[s.index.notna()]
Out[22]:
0.0    0
1.0    0
2.0    1
4.0    1
3.0    2
dtype: int32
```

Comment: http://justflipacoin.com/ Turned out to be heads and you won. But I appreciate all the answers, so thanks all!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, ha-ha, thanks for such a useful link ! :-D

Answer (score 3):

Use filtering:

```
print (s[s.index.notnull()])
```

Or similar:

```
print (s[~np.isnan(s.index)])

0.0    0
1.0    0
2.0    1
4.0    1
3.0    2
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Both answers are perfect, which to accept :-(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, just flip a coin :-D

Comment: use coin for this ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
s[s.index.dropna()]

Out: 
0.0    0
1.0    0
2.0    1
4.0    1
3.0    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Nice to see you back :)

Comment: only concern is dealing with duplicates in the index. A mask might be more suited to that.

Comment: @MaxU Thank you. I am here actually but not posting as before. :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah noticed that while trying to time it. :)

Comment: It is slower by the way. I was hoping getting the actual indexes may work faster than boolean indexing (it does in some cases) but it it not the case here.